# How to calculate specific rating count hash in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, after-save

So, I have an **after_save** hook on **review** model which calls **calculate_specific_rating** function of product model. The function goes like this:

```
def calculate_specific_rating
    ratings = reviews.reload.all.pluck(:rating)
    specific_rating = Hash.new(0)
    ratings.each { |rating| specific_rating[rating] += 1 }
    self.specific_rating = specific_rating
    save
  end
```

Right now,  it returns

```
specific_rating => { 
"2"=> 3, "4"=> 1
}
```

I want it to return like:

```
specific_rating => { 
"1"=> 0, "2"=>3, "3"=>0, "4"=>1, "5"=>0
}
```

Also, is it okay to initialize a new hash everytime a review is saved? I want some alternative. Thanks

Comment: What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma its 2.6.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a range from 1 until the maximum value in `ratings` plus 1 and start iterating through it, yielding an array where the first element is the current one, and the second element is the total of times the current element is present in `ratings`. After everything the result is converted to a hash:

```
self.specific_rating = (1..ratings.max + 1).to_h { |e| [e.to_s, ratings.count(e)] }
save
```

Comment: thanks !! What should we do to initialize the hash values to zero when the product is first created. and to use the above function once the rating is created on that product

Comment: You can do that in the migration, adding a default value for that column when the record is created @twinkle.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this -

```
def calculate_specific_rating
  ratings = [1,2,3,4,5]
  existing_ratings = reviews.group_by(&:rating).map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}.to_h
  Hash[(ratings - existing_ratings.keys).map {|x| [x, 0]}].merge(existing_ratings)
end
```

which gives

> {3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 2=>3, 1=>1}